# OpenAcc if-condition not working?

Tags: if-statement, openacc

I have the following code:

```
#pragma acc kernels
for (i = 0; i<shape1Count; i++){
    for (j = 0; j<shape2Count; j++){

        if (kkk==1){
            intersectionsCount++;
        } else {
            intersectionsCount++;
        }

    }
}
```

kkk is assigned with 1.
I found that the if-condition has not even run, that means no matter it is true or false, intersectionCount is not incremented.

My assumption is, if-condition cannot be handled by GPU/accelerator. Is it true?

If it is true, what can I do to handle this?

p.s. I am very new to GPU programming.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What compiler are you using and on what platform? This should run, although it'll probably run better if the increment is implemented with an atomic directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often the compiler can auto-detect reductions but not in this case.  Hence, you need to add a reduction clause yourself.  Here's the output when using pgcc version 16.4:

```
% cat test.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int i, j, kkk, intersectionsCount;
int shape1Count,shape2Count;

shape1Count=32;
shape2Count=32;
intersectionsCount=0;
kkk=1;

#pragma acc kernels loop reduction(+:intersectionsCount)
for (i = 0; i<shape1Count; i++){
    for (j = 0; j<shape2Count; j++){
        if (kkk==1){
            intersectionsCount++;
        } else {
            intersectionsCount++;
        }
    }
}
printf("%d\n",intersectionsCount);
exit(0);
}
% pgcc test.c -Minfo=accel -acc; a.out
main:
     15, Loop is parallelizable
     16, Loop is parallelizable
         Accelerator kernel generated
         Generating Tesla code
         15, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(4) /* blockIdx.y threadIdx.y */
         16, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(32) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
             Generating reduction(+:intersectionsCount)
1024
```

Comment: man! you saved my life! "reduction" is the new stuff I learnt here. Thanks a lot